# Make a Circle Radius Based on viewportwidth (vw)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, gsap

I have a free jQuery image gallery that I am trying to make some modifications to to make it suit my project.

The gallery is a spinning circle with images.

The radius of the circle is defined in this manner:

```
radius = Math.round( (250) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );
```

However what I need is to make a new radius based on viewportwidth (vw)

Can anyone help me approach this correctly?

Also I would be very appreciative if someone would help me understand what is happening in the above code.

Here is the context for that line of code:

```
w = $(window);
container = $( '#contentContainer' );
carousel = $( '#carouselContainer' );
item = $( '.carouselItem' );
itemLength = $( '.carouselItem' ).length;
fps = $('#fps');
rY = 360 / itemLength;
radius = Math.round( (250) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mxp5svjx/

here is a picture as requested:

[image]

the main problem is when i resize the window then radius of the circle stays the same.

here is a working demo: 
http://codepen.io/johnblazek/full/nceyw/

Comment: Can you give us an image of the gallery in action? It might help to understand what the code does in relation to the gallery.

Comment: when I open the working demo in Opera it completely freaks out.

Comment: the demo works fine when i open it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out the Key is 250. 250 is 13.02% of 1920 assuming you have a 1920px width window which I do. So i fiqured out I need 13.02% of window width.

I have obtained that by doing this:

```
radius = Math.round10( (($(window).width()) * 0.1302) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );

Math.round10(); // rounds to the nearest decimal. 
$(window).width(); // is the width of the window. In my case 1920px
0.1302 is 13.02% // when you multiply it with something.
```

Final result is that I get a radius based on 13.02vw

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think

```
Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength )
```

is calculating the angle of each segment, the higher the value of `itemLength` gets, the smaller the angle. All items need to fit in the circle. The `tan` function generates a value depending on the angle value.

Then 250 is divided by the former result.
I guess swapping 250 with `vw` results in too high a value.
If you know the viewwidth it looks good on already then you can try something like:

```
radius = Math.round( (250 * (vw/default_vw) ) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );
```

Comment: It makes a little sense what you are saying. However it does not work. 

I have added a little more code. perhaps it can help.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am getting closer. I found out the number 250 is the key. I need to somehow set that number to 13vw

Comment: I have tried like this: radius = Math.round( (0.1302 * $(window).width()) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );  but this gives the same result as the number 250

Comment: if your screensize is 1920 then the multiplication results in 250. The jsfiddle shows an empty screen on run.